# Go global variable and short variable definition

Tags: go

In the following snippet

```
package ...

var Conn *sql.DB // outer Conn

func Init(user, pwd, dbname string, port int) {
    Conn, err := sql.Open("postgres", "... args") // inner Conn
    // ..
}
```

the inner `Conn` is a new variable and *outer* `Conn` will remain null.

By explicitly defining `err` and replacing the short variable definition with assignment it seems to properly init the outer `Conn` variable

```
    var err error
    Conn, err = sql.Open("postgres", "... args") // inner Conn
```

Is there a simpler way to specify the inner `Conn` should not really be a scoped variable but instead the global `Conn` variable? I'm thinking something like `package.Conn`, but that's invalid inside the package itself.

Comment: No. But is it really that long that you want to shorten it? If yes, then also make the `err` variable global...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, that's it. `:=` is just a shortcut to <strike>New() (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new)</strike> variable declaration (var foo int). A more idiomatic approach (and better design in general) is to return the connection and not to use global variables.

```golang
func Init(user string, pwd string, dbname string, port int) (*sql.DB, error) {
    // ...
}
```

Dependency injection is your friend, try not to break scope.

Comment: ":= is just a shortcut to New()" doesn't seem right: `new()` returns a pointer but `x := 1` doesn't create a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no shorthand for this. `:=` always assigns to variables in the current (innermost) scope, creating new variables if necessary. To assign to any variables outside the current scope, you must use `=` instead of `:=`, and in the case of multiple-assignment this means that all variables must be pre-declared.